# NServiceBus: Custom IConfigurationSource for UnicastBusConfig

Tags: nservicebus

I'm trying to move NServiceBus UnicastBusConfig from Web.config to (VB.NET) code and I'm having some problems doing so. The original Web.config looked like the following:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="Messages" Endpoint="TSInputQueue" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

And when the bus was configured with this, the "assembliesToEndpoints" property ended up looking like this and everything worked OK:

[image: Debug image]

Then I removed the configuration from Web.config and created a new IConfigurationSource:

```
Public Class UnicastBusConfigurator
Implements IConfigurationSource

Public Function GetConfiguration(Of T As Class)() As T Implements NServiceBus.Config.ConfigurationSource.IConfigurationSource.GetConfiguration

    If (GetType(T) Is GetType(UnicastBusConfig)) Then

        Dim mapping = New MessageEndpointMapping()
        mapping.Endpoint = "InputQueue"
        mapping.Messages = "Messages"

        Dim unicastBusConfig As UnicastBusConfig = New UnicastBusConfig()
        unicastBusConfig.MessageEndpointMappings.Add(New MessageEndpointMapping())

        Return TryCast(unicastBusConfig, T)

    End If

    Return TryCast(ConfigurationManager.GetSection(GetType(T).Name), T)

End Function

End Class
```

And I added the following part to the bus initialization (for some reason the extension methods aren't working...):

```
config = config.CustomConfigurationSource(New UnicastBusConfigurator)
```

I've made sure that the UnicastBusConfigurator's GetConfiguration-method is executed, but the assembliesToEndpoints-property doesn't look right:

[image: NServiceBus endpoints]

Note the third row in HashTable, which is empty. Now, the config.CreateBus().Start() fails:

> Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus' : Error setting property values: PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested PropertyAccessExceptions are: 
>   [Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property value of type [System.Collections.Hashtable] to required type [System.Collections.IDictionary] for property 'MessageOwners'., Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: Problem loading message assembly:  ---> System.ArgumentException: String cannot have zero length.

The exception seems to be caused by the empty row ("String cannot have zero length.").

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that code didn't actually add the mapping to the collection. The code add a new empty MessageEndpointMapping.  I think it should read:

```
unicastBusConfig.MessageEndpointMappings.Add(mapping)
```

This should give NSB something to map to.

Comment: Gah! How one can get so blind when he stares at the same code too long! :) Thank you!